# AS3: FPS drops down significantly because of innocent mouse moves

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, frame-rate

I have ~10000 objects in my game and exactly 60 (maximum) FPS when mouse isn't moved. But just when you start moving mouse in circles FPS tries to reach 30 averaging at 45. When you stop mouse it's INSTANTLY 60 (as so program lost it's heartbeat). SWF is run standalone - without any browsers.

I removed any `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` listeners and made `mouseEnabled=false` and `mouseChildren=false` for the main class.

I increased my FPS one-by-one from 12 to 60 - I gave name to each frame I born and it's really painful watching how 15 of them die just because of nothing...

Sample code:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var _periods : int = 0;

    /** Idling FPS is 23. Move mouse to drop FPS to 21.*/
    public function Main() : void
    {
        //true if need to drop FPS to 18 instead of 21 moving mouse:
        const readyToKill2MoreFrames : Boolean = true;
        if ( readyToKill2MoreFrames )
        {
            var ellipse : Sprite = new Sprite;
            ellipse.graphics.beginFill( 0x00FF00 );
            ellipse.graphics.drawEllipse( 300, 300, 400, 200 );
            ellipse.graphics.endFill();
            addChild( ellipse );

            //uncomment to fall only to 21 instead of 18:
            /*ellipse.mouseChildren = false;
            ellipse.mouseEnabled = false;*/
        }

        var fps : TextField = new TextField;
        //uncommenting doesn't change FPS:
        //fps.mouseEnabled = false;
        addChild( fps );
        fps.text = "???";
        fps.scaleX = fps.scaleY = 3;
        var timer : Timer = new Timer( 1000 );
        timer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, function( ... args ) : void
        {
            fps.text = _periods.toString();
            _periods = 0;
        } );
        timer.start();

        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, function( ... args ) : void
        {
            //seems like PC is too fast to demonstrate mouse movement
            // drawbacks when he has nothing else to do, so let's make
            // his attention flow:
            for ( var i : int = 0; i < 500000; ++i )
            {
                var j : int = 2 + 2;
            }

            ++_periods;
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: The objects are static or dynamic?

Comment: Would be hard to help you at all without the actual code. It certainly sounds like you have some kind of logic that is running based on mouse movement.  Does any logic react to mouse movement itself ? For example are you tracking mouseX, mouseY and then triggering some kind of logic based on that. But, seems pointless to play performance charades. Post the code and maybe someone can evaluate based on that.

Comment: Sorry for that, but my project's code is ~100000 lines long while it's pretty simple: 10000 objects are drawn using bitmap blitting onto Bitmap which addChilded() at Main class. Mouse selection is done each ENTER_FRAME using stage.mouseX/Y. Rich and sophisticated interface elements (which are added upon everything using MovieClips technique) are present, but their removing doesn't change anything.

Comment: Seems like I've got a little closer to the actual cause - added some clause into the sample.

Comment: Provided code does not show any fps drop at my notebook. At all. Please provide information about sdk and swf version. Are you using any framework (Starling or something, 10k is a lot)? There are few topics about this, but they are ancient :) http://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4351

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably moved on to more modern problems, but I've recently struggled with this issue myself, so here's an answer for future unfortunates stuck with the problems created by Adobe's decade-old sins.

It turns out legacy support for old-style buttons is the culprit. Quote from Adobe's [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/understanding-flashplayer-with-scout.html) on the excellent Scout profiling tool:

> "Flash Player has some special code to handle old-style button objects (the kind that you create in Flash Professional).
>   Independently of looking for ActionScript event handlers for mouse
>   events, it searches the display list for any of these buttons whenever
>   the mouse moves. This can be expensive if you have a large number of
>   objects on the display list. Unfortunately, this operation happens
>   even if you don't use old-style button objects, but Adobe is working
>   on a fix for this."

Turns out Adobe never really got around to fixing this, so any large number of `DisplayObjects` will wreak havoc on your FPS while the mouse is moved. Only fix is to merge them somehow, e.g. by batch drawing them using `Graphics`. In my early tests, it seems setting `mouseEnabled = false` has no real effect, either.

Comment: I was working with Flash for like 5 years already and moving to TypeScript since yesterday, getting this response just now, LOL. What a coincidence.